# Why is this package not shown in Synaptic Package Manager

Tags: package-management

I was wondering  why this package is not found in Synaptic Package Manager: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/any2djvu.1.html, while it is shown in http://manpages.ubuntu.com/.

My OS is 10.10.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: "djvulibre-bin" shows up here, Linux Mint 10, based upon Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Thanks! How did you know it is inside djvulibre-bin?

Comment: That's shown on the manpage website in the "Provided by" line right over the NAME headline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`any2djvu` is a command and not a package. Synaptice/USC you search for packages.
The answer to your questions is also on the manpage:

```
natty (1) any2djvu.1.gz
Provided by: **djvulibre-bin_3.5.23-3ubuntu2_i386**

SEE ALSO: The entire djvu suite, eg djvu(1), djview(1), and djvuserver(1).
```

You need to search for `djvu` in synaptic. Most likely want your want is the [djvulibre](http://packages.ubuntu.com/djvulibre) package.

[image: Install djvulibre]